# Store an array of arrays in its own class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, data-structures

I've written a program where I have 4 numbers. 
The first number is an ID. (int)
The other 3 are just points on a map. (double)

I would like to create an array of arrays in its own class ideally where it stores these 3 numbers and uses the first one as an ID.

Is an arraylist a good method?
I'm really just struggling on the data structure. It's simple in what it is. I just need to store a bunch of numbers in an array of arrays. I can do that. However storing it in a different class is difficult.

Comment: if you wish to do an id based look up then use HashMap. Use an arraylist only if  you need to do an sequential access or index based access.

Comment: " would like to create an array of arrays in its own class ideally where it stores these 3 numbers and uses the first one as an ID." - what is the array of arrays of?  Firstly the id should be its own `int id;` not part of the array, but I don't get where the other array comes from.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java is an object oriented language just use a custom class:

```
class MyPoint {
  double x, y, z;
}
```

or if you really need an array

```
class MyPoint {
  double[] coords;
}
```

Then it depends what your id is, if it's a autoincrement value with no "holes" you can just have an `ArrayList<MyPoint>` if you need random access.

If it's a sparse index and you still need random access then use a `HashMap<Integer, MyPoint>`. You can have use a `TreeMap<Integer, MyPoint>` if you need to have them ordered (by id or by position).

Answer (score 1):

If the three points are related to each other, consider introducing a type for them, like `MyPoints` and store them in a map for lookup like this:

`Map<Integer, MyPoints> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, MyPoints>`

Remember to override `hashCode` and `equals` methods for `MyPoints` for the map to function as expected, i.e. considering two `MyPoint` instances with identical content as equal.

Comment: @PeterRader - there are no keys and values in a Set, just entries, like in HashSet<E>

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a `Map` and use your id as Key, and then a array with your points.

```
Map<Integer,Double[]> map = new HashMap<Integer,Double[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new class 4 that.

```
Number[][] lst = {{1, 3.0, 4.0, 11.0, 443.f}};
```

Or something like this:

```
HashSet<Integer, <ArrayList<Double>> items = new HashSet<Integer, <ArrayList<Double>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution will be like this.

```
class MyPoint {
    int id;
    double[] coordinate= new double[3];
    MyPoint(int id, double x,double y, double z) {
        this.id = id;
        coordinate[0]= x;
        coordinate[1]= y;
        coordinate[2]= z;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public double[] getCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }
}

class MyPoints extends ArrayList<MyPoint> {
    public void addPoint(int id, double x,double y, double z) {
        super.add(new MyPoint(id,x,y,z));
    }
}
```

Note:
If you need to find MyPoint with id, then you can use HashMap;

```
class MyPointWithHashMap extends HashMap<Integer,MyPoint> {
    public void addPoint(int id, double x,double y, double z) {
        super.put(id,new MyPoint(id,x,y,z));
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use a hashmap with this? =S

Answer (score 0):

I might create a wrapper class for your three-point coordinate system, but not for the entire thing including ID.  The ID should probably be separate, since it's a level of abstraction above the coordinate itself.

```
public class Point {

    double x, y, z;

    //standard constructors, getters, setters

}
```

Then, wherever you're using this from, you can do...

```
HashMap<Integer, Point> map = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
int id = 0;
```

... and for each of your points ...

```
map.put(id++, point);
```

This gives each of your coordinate sets a unique ID while not making the ID an intrinsic part of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a model class and use it in your controller class? I think that will me much easier.

```
class SomeModel {
    // getters and setters }


class Controller {
   public SomeModel model;

   //getter and setter for model
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `MultiMap` from Apache Commons Collections: [See here](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html)

`MultiMap` associates several values for a same key. (this is transparent this is why `MultiMap` can be useful in this case).

```
MultiMap idWithDoubles = new MultiHashMap();
 idWithDoubles.put(1, 1.1);
 idWithDoubles.put(1, 1.2);
 idWithDoubles.put(1, 1.3);
```

You can then retrieve the Doubles list for a particular id:

```
 List list = (List) idWithDoubles.get(1);
```

returning by default an `ArrayList` with the values: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3

You can also see the Guava version (most up-to-date) here:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0):

If the mixed types are required (int/double), then you'll need a class. Something like this:

```
public class MapPoints {
    private int id;

    private double point1;

    private double point2;

    private double point3;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setPoint1(double point1) {
        this.point1 = point1;
    }

    public double getPoint1() {
        return point1;
    }

    public void setPoint2(double point2) {
        this.point2 = point2;
    }

    public double getPoint2() {
        return point2;
    }

    public void setPoint3(double point3) {
        this.point3 = point3;
    }

    public double getPoint3() {
        return point3;
    }

}
```

If you only have 3 points, I don't see why you'd even bother with an array. That just introduces ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException possibilities.

After that, you could just have an ArrayList object to hold all of these.

However, if the ID can be a float, then Peter's answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sine java is OO

```
public class MyPoint extends Point.Double{

    private double z;

    public MyPoint(double x, doubley, doublez) {
        super(x, y);
        this.setZ(z);
    }

    public double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(double z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "MyPoint[" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map`

```
Map<Integer, Double[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
```

So for each Integer ID you have a set of values associated.

To traverse the `HashMap`,

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry hashValues = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(hashValues.getKey() + " = " + hashValues.getValue());
}
```

Get the value in an Double array and travese it for each key.